# how to build index in mongodb in this situation

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a mongodb database, which has following fields:

**{"word":"ipad", "date":20140113, "docid": 324, "score": 98}**

which is a reverse index for a log of docs(about 120 millions).

there are two kinds of queries in my system:
one of which is :

**db.index.find({"word":"ipad", "date":20140113}).sort({"score":-1})**

this query fetch the word "ipad" in date 20140113, and sort the all docs by score.

another query is:

**db.index.find({"word":"ipad", "date":20140113, "docid":324})**

to speed up these two kinds of query, what index should I build?

Should I build two indexes like this?:

**db.index.ensureIndex({"word":1, "date":1, "docid":1}, {"unique":true})**

**db.index.ensureIndex({"word":1, "date":1, "score":1}**

but I think build the two index use two much hard disk space.

So do you have some good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting by score descending (`.sort({"score":-1})`), which means that your index should also be descending on the score-field so it can support the sorting:

```
db.index.ensureIndex({"word":1, "date":1, "score":-1});
```

The other index looks good to speed up that query, but you still might want to confirm that by running the query in the mongo shell followed with [`.explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/).

Indexes are always a tradeoff of space and write-performance for read-performance. When you can't afford the space, you can't have the index and have to deal with it. But usually the write-performance is the larger concern, because drive space is usually cheap.

But maybe you could save one of the three indexes you have. "Wait, three indexes?" Yes, keep in mind that every collection *must* have an unique index on the _id field which is created implicitely when the collection is initialized.

But the _id field doesn't have to be an auto-generated ObjectId. It can be anything you want. When you have another index with an uniqueness-constraint and you have no use for the _id field, you can move that unique-constraint to the _id field to save an index. Your documents would then look like this:

```
{ _id: { 
     "word":"ipad", 
     "date":20140113, 
     "docid": 324
  },
  "score": 98
}
```